# What is the difference between a one party state & non-partisan democracy?

Tags: democracy, political-theory, political-system, terminology

A [one-party state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-party_state) often in practice appears to consider that all nationals are de-facto members of the ruling party, so how is there really any difference between that & a [non-partisan democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-partisan_democracy)?

*Is it just semantics or are there any real differences.*

Answer (score 8):

In a one-party state, the party leadership usually sets the rules, which are binding for all party members and/or citizens.

In a non-partisan democracy, every candidate or representative can form and voice their own opinions. A non-partisan democracy lacks a [Politburo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politburo).